# large dictionary in python exceed RAM capacity

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, large-files, large-data

I am having a question on how Python function.
I have a very large dataset (200 GB) and I am going to use python to iterate through lines, store data in a dictionary and then perform some calculation. Finally, I will write the computed data to a CSV file.
My concern is the capacity of my computer. I am afraid (or pretty sure) my RAM cannot store that large dataset. Is there a better way?
Here is the structure of input data:

```
#RIC    Date[L] Time[L] Type    ALP-L1-BidPrice ALP-L1-BidSize  ALP-L1-AskPrice ALP-L1-AskSize  ALP-L2-BidPrice ALP-L2-BidSize  ALP-L2-AskPrice ALP-L2-AskSize  ALP-L3-BidPrice ALP-L3-BidSize  ALP-L3-AskPrice ALP-L3-AskSize  ALP-L4-BidPrice ALP-L4-BidSize  ALP-L4-AskPrice ALP-L4-AskSize  ALP-L5-BidPrice ALP-L5-BidSize  ALP-L5-AskPrice ALP-L5-AskSize  TOR-L1-BidPrice TOR-L1-BidSize  TOR-L1-AskPrice TOR-L1-AskSize  TOR-L2-BidPrice TOR-L2-BidSize  TOR-L2-AskPrice TOR-L2-AskSize  TOR-L3-BidPrice TOR-L3-BidSize  TOR-L3-AskPrice TOR-L3-AskSize  TOR-L4-BidPrice TOR-L4-BidSize  TOR-L4-AskPrice TOR-L4-AskSize  TOR-L5-BidPrice TOR-L5-BidSize  TOR-L5-AskPrice TOR-L5-AskSize
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:10.8 Market Depth    5.29    50000   5.3 16000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000   5.29    50000   5.3 46000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:10.8 Market Depth    5.29    50000   5.3 22000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000   5.29    50000   5.3 36000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:10.8 Market Depth    5.29    50000   5.3 32000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000   5.29    50000   5.3 40000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:10.8 Market Depth    5.29    50000   5.3 44000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000   5.29    50000   5.3 36000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 Market Depth    5.29    50000   5.3 32000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000   5.29    50000   5.3 46000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 Market Depth    5.29    50000   5.3 38000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000   5.29    50000   5.3 36000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000
```

Here is what I attempt to do:
1. read in ta data and store them into a dictionary with keys [symbol][time][bid] and [ask] etc
2. at any point in time, find the best bid price and best ask price (this requires sorting horizontally/among the values in the key which I don't know how) as the bid and ask prices come from different exchanges, we need to find the best prices and rank them from the best to the worst along with volume for that particular price.
3. export to a csv file.

Here is my attempt fot the codes. Please help me to write it more efficient:

```
# this file calculate the depth up to $50,000

import csv
from math import ceil
from collections import defaultdict

# open csv file
csv_file = open('2016_01_04-data_3_stocks.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

# Set variables:
date = None
exchange_depth = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))))
effective_spread = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))))
time_bucket = [i * 100000.0 for i in range(0, 57600000000 / 100000)]

# Set functions
def time_to_milli(times):
    hours = float(times.split(':')[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000000
    minutes = float(times.split(':')[1]) * 60 * 1000000
    seconds = float(times.split(':')[2]) * 1000000
    milliseconds = float(times.split('.')[1])
    timestamp = hours + minutes + seconds + milliseconds
    return timestamp


# Extract data
for i in reader:
    if not bool(date):
        date = i['Date[L]'][0:4] + "-" + i['Date[L]'][4:6] + "-" + i['Date[L]'][6:8]
    security = i['#RIC'].split('.')[0]
    exchange = i['#RIC'].split('.')[1]
    timestamp = float(time_to_milli(i['Time[L]']))
    bucket = ceil(float(time_to_milli(i['Time[L]'])) / 100000.0) * 100000.0
    # input bid price and bid size
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid][i['ALP-L1-BidPrice']] += i['ALP-L1-BidSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid][i['ALP-L2-BidPrice']] += i['ALP-L2-BidSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid][i['ALP-L3-BidPrice']] += i['ALP-L3-BidSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid][i['ALP-L4-BidPrice']] += i['ALP-L4-BidSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid][i['ALP-L5-BidPrice']] += i['ALP-L5-BidSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid][i['TOR-L1-BidPrice']] += i['TOR-L1-BidSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid][i['TOR-L2-BidPrice']] += i['TOR-L2-BidSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid][i['TOR-L3-BidPrice']] += i['TOR-L3-BidSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid][i['TOR-L4-BidPrice']] += i['TOR-L4-BidSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid][i['TOR-L5-BidPrice']] += i['TOR-L5-BidSize']
    # input ask price and ask size
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask][i['ALP-L1-AskPrice']] += i['ALP-L1-AskSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask][i['ALP-L2-AskPrice']] += i['ALP-L2-AskSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask][i['ALP-L3-AskPrice']] += i['ALP-L3-AskSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask][i['ALP-L4-AskPrice']] += i['ALP-L4-AskSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask][i['ALP-L5-AskPrice']] += i['ALP-L5-AskSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask][i['TOR-L1-AskPrice']] += i['TOR-L1-AskSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask][i['TOR-L2-AskPrice']] += i['TOR-L2-AskSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask][i['TOR-L3-AskPrice']] += i['TOR-L3-AskSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask][i['TOR-L4-AskPrice']] += i['TOR-L4-AskSize']
    exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask][i['TOR-L5-AskPrice']] += i['TOR-L5-AskSize']
# Now rank bid price and ask price among exchange_depth[security][bucket][Bid] and exchange_depth[security][bucket][Ask] keys
    #I don't know how to do this
```

Comment: If you process line by line, and the dictionary you use to process the data does not exceed your RAM, you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: As @FranciscoCouzo said, if you _iterate_ through the lines (not loading everything in memory) and the dictionary is reasonably small, you should be ok. However, if you provided some sample data (a few lines of the dataset) and the type of calculations you are trying to perform, we could probably give you a better answer.

Comment: this seems too broad or lacking a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will upload the codes soon. Generally, I am going to read in data line by line and store them into a dictionary in which I will do my calculation. To my understanding, dictionaries will be stored in RAM, am I correct?

Comment: Hi guys, I have edited the posts. Please let me know what needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've told us, here's what you can do:

```
import csv
with open("path/to/my_dataset", 'r') as input_f, open("output.csv", 'a') as output_f:
    # Keep reading lines from input data until you run out
    for line in f:
        # do processing and add to processed
        processed = []

        # write processed data to output file
        csv.writer(output_f).writerow(processed)
```

Comment: Little confused as to why you don't just for `for line_num, line in enumerate(f, 1):` instead of two `readline` calls outside and inside a `while` loop with manual line number counting. Also, why you don't just open the output file once, wrap in `csv.writer` once, and write each line as you finish, saving the not insubstantial cost of constantly opening and closing the file; batching them is pointless, the file object will buffer for you anyway.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right, I just went fast through this. Those are good simplifications.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Batching the writes can be useful if you write to your output file only once every x number of input lines.

Comment: That's why I mentioned buffering. Even if you "write" every line, simple file objects buffer; you might call `write` 100 times, but it only actually performs a real write to the underlying file every time the buffer files. If the average write is 100 bytes, and the buffer is 8KB (Python default buffer size), those 100 calls to `write` only actually perform a system call to write to the backing file twice. If that's too often, increase the buffer size (it's an optional argument); manually batching is almost never advantageous.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the input format and my code attempt